# Can JMeter JDBC pre-processor accept multiple Insert queries?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I'm creating a `Thread Group`, and before sample execution want to seed the database with test data. According to the JMeter manual, I need `JDBC pre-processor`.

I insert multiple insert queries into the `pre-processor` but it looks like it doesn't create an entry in database. I tried to replace the `pre-processor` with multiple samples - and everything is fine.

Can JMeter `pre-processors` receive multiple `INSERT` queries?

Comment: Did you try multiple pre-processors? I haven't used that one, but I _think_ it is only one command per sample.

Comment: Yes it can, but if it is hard for you then use multiple JDBC Request for multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter JDBC Test Elements execute [SQL queries](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/), any correct SQL query will be executed. Current design is "one element - one query", however you can try using [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator to merge 2 or more queries into one.

JDBC Test Elements can also be parameterised like any other test elements so you can call i.e. [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler multiple times and each time send to it different data via [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Also if you need to populate the database with test data I would recommend going for [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)